# hasManyThrough is returning only one result instead of all

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relationship

The platform has a many to many relationship, where the table `assigned_users` holds all `Users` assigned to `CalendarEvents`.

[image]

I need to fetch, through `CalendarEvents`, the assigned users as an object, showing each user's information. So, I want to access the `User` through `AssignedUsers`, because I wanna fetch all the users related to that event.

```
public function assignedUsers()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Users::class, AssignedUsers::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

It works, but it shows only the first user in the table. I want to show all of them. Currently there are 3.

```
"assigned_users": [
    { id: 1, ... }
]
```

If I do the following:

```
public function assignedUsers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Users::class, "assigned_users", "event_id", "event_id");
}
```

It will fetch 3 results, but all the information will be from the same user. It will repeat the same user 3 times. Changing both the `event_id` to `user_id` and `id`, and `id` and `user_id` will have the same result.

```
"assigned_users": [
    { id: 1, ... },
    { id: 1, ... },
    { id: 1, ... },
    ...
]
```

What I am trying to accomplish is the following result:

```
{
    "status": "200",
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "event_id": 1,
            "event_key": "EB1M7OGJRPW0",
            "calendar_id": 4,
            "start_at": "2018-01-01 00:00:00",
            "end_at": "2018-01-31 00:00:00",
            "location": "123 Lorem, Ipsum",
            "event_name": "Event #1",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "added_at": "2018-02-07 09:07:31",
            "created_by": {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Foo Bar",
                "email": "foobar92@gmail.com",
                "first_name": "Foo",
                "last_name": "Bar",
                "status": "active",
                "is_activated": 0,
                "created_at": "2018-02-07 09:06:49",
                "updated_at": "2018-02-07 09:06:49"
            },
            "assigned_users": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    ...
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    ...
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    ...
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the case of hasManyThrough relationship. Here assigned_users is a pivot table so you just need a belongsToMany relationship defined

```
public function assignedUsers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Users::class, 'assigned_users', 'event_id', 'user_id');
}
```

and for this to work, you may have to change the calendar_events table's primary key to `id` (instead of `event_id`)

Comment: I got so close though. Much appreciated, Afzal.

Comment: Happy to help! Cheers!